# JLabel only showing the last label

Tags: jlabel

I'm trying to create multiple labels on a Frame. Every example I've seen has done it exactly how I've done it...

```
JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Label 1");
JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Label 2");
//... goes on through label5

frame.add(label1);
frame.add(label2);
//... etc through label 5.
```

Only label 5 is being display. If I comment out 5, only label 4 is display. It's only displaying whatever the last label is.

Comment: Are you using getContentPane() method?

Comment: Apparently it's because I wasn't using a layout manager. Setup a frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout(); and although it's still not pretty, it gets everything on the screen and gets me to the next step.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which LayoutManager you have set. Probably you left the default `BorderLayout` and therefore all of them are added to center and streched to window size. So the last added one - of course - covers all the previously added labels. Try using a `FlowLayout` or something else: See this [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

So assuming you are creating the GUI elements within a child of `JFrame`, this is how a layout manager is set:

```
setLayout(new FlowLayout());
//...
add(label1);
add(label2);
add(label3);
//...
```